# Selecting records where two rows are met but if not select them all

Tags: sql

I have a table like this where i want to select all records except where two columns match certain values

```
id    Signal_Type     Input
1     Alarm           2
1     Alarm           4
1     Video           1
2     Alarm           4
2     Video           5 
2     Alarm           7
```

I would like to select all records where ID = 1 and where Signal_Type != Alarm and Input != 2, but if both the Signal_Type and input arent matched then still show the record.

```
SELECT *
FROM ReceiverAlarms
WHERE id = '1' AND (Signal_Type != 'Alarm' AND Input != '2')
```

I expected this query to return

```
id    Signal_Type      Input
1     Alarm            4
1     Video            1
```

but instead it returns nothing.

Im sure there will be other questions on here asking for that but i wasnt sure how to word it to find what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"if both the type and input arent matched then still show the record."*
That's an `OR`
`(Type != 'Alarm' OR Input != '2')`

Below demo is for MySQL, but this will work for any DBMS

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE ReceiverAlarms (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `Type` VARCHAR(5),
  `Input` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO ReceiverAlarms
  (`id`, `Type`, `Input`)
VALUES
  (1, 'Alarm', 2),
  (1, 'Alarm', 4),
  (1, 'Video', 1),
  (2, 'Alarm', 4),
  (2, 'Video', 5),
  (2, 'Alarm', 7);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM ReceiverAlarms
WHERE id = '1' AND (Type != 'Alarm' OR Input != '2');
```

**Output**

```
| id  | Type  | Input |
| --- | ----- | ----- |
| 1   | Alarm | 4     |
| 1   | Video | 1     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bE9ZQNro2oGS6UAwR82nvP/0)

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly, dont know how i missed that

Answer (score 0):

You can try below way -

```
select id, type,max(input) as input
from tablename
where id=1
group by id,type
```